# post NOT predifined messages on facebook wall from android application

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to create an android application which would allow the users to post messages on their facebook wall and also on their friends wall.
I've been through a few tutorials but in each of them is done barely the same thing:integrate facebook in application, the login authorization and posting a predifined message on the walll.

I'm using facebook sdk and I wonder is possible for the user to write directly to his wall in a dialog window???
What kind of authorization I need and if u could give me an example would be great.Thank u!

Comment: Your question is too broad. The tutorials probably already teach you how to integrate Facebook in an application, how to login and how to post a message. Then take a look at Android tutorials about EditText and you should be able to put all this together. I you still have troubles you can ask here, but you will hopefully have a more precise question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what more precise than this-I want to write to my fb wall from my application in the same way I do when I open my fb page in mozilla,let say(I want to see the wall on the screen of my PHONE and write there).For now the only tutorial I have found integrate fb in app and do a login!!!If u could direct me to a tutorial that for example allows u to see your personal information(Info) then I would appreciate it!!

Comment: There are a lot of thing to do to post a message on the wall. In particular you have to login to Facebook (1), you have to ask the user for some text (2), and you have to post this as a message on the wall (3). This should be at least three different questions. Fortunately, you know how to do the first one (in the tutorial you found), the second one is explained in every tutorial about Android, and the third one is probably documented in the Facebook API.

Comment: Can u give me a link to a tutorial that shows how to retrieve the user's profile on android after he logged in?

Comment: No because I don’t know any tutorial about Facebook. But the tutorial you found is probably already explaining how to use the Facebook API.

Comment: :)))...Great only that I'm so dull that I can't see that.Have a good day:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) and there is part 2 [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2). It will guide you though setting up the application to use facebook. Once you have all that setup you can use a function like this to post a msg to someones wall:

```
/**
 * Post to a friends wall
 * @param msg Message to post
 * @param userId Id for friend to post to or null to post to users wall
 */
public void postToWall(String msg, String userID) {
    try {
        if (isSession()) {
            String response = mFacebook.request((userID == null) ? "me" : userID);
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", msg);
            response = mFacebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d(TAG,response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
                Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }

        } else {
            // no logged in, so relogin
            Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```